# Problems in dropping and re-populate mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a myqsl database that I populate with .csv file through a php page. The process is performed with no problem.
The issue shows up when I update the database with the modified .csv file having some new rows and some different data in the old rows.
Updating operations are:
1st. deleting the database.
2nd. populating with the correct .csv
Result: the database can't populate correctly, I see only the last row.
I tried different ways to empty the database: with DROP command and with the following commands:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "RENAME TABLE `mytable` TO t1");
mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE `mytable` LIKE t1");
mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE t1");
```

In both cases I don't see differences. Furthermore I noticed that if I place the "empting" strings close or far the "INSERT" command the number of rows populated is different.
Is there a way to fix the issue? It seems a problem of executing time, I presume. Is there a way to order one task (emptying) and when it ends, follow the other task (populating). Any help?

Comment: To delete all data in a table you would normally use [TRUNCATE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-truncate-table/). After that you should be able to read new CVS data. Note that `TRUNCATE` also resets value in the `AUTO_INCREMENT`  column.

Comment: Did you actually check that all these commands were completed without error? Check the status returned from the call to query

Comment: Why don't you just check which records are new and which needs an update? Mysql is a relational database, you shouldn't just drop all data and reinsert as this will mess with auto-increments and could lead to misinformation in your database